# Remove quotes from a character vector in R?

Tags: regex, r, quotes

I have some text:

```
version of mackinnon’s “dominance approach,”
```

which I've read into a character vector:

```
> my.char.vector
[1] "version" "of" "mackinnon’s" "“dominance" "approach,”"
```

How can I remove double (and single) quotes, such that my.char.vector is

```
[1] "version" "of" "mackinnons" "dominance" "approach,"
```

The other question with this exact title is not, in fact, asking the same question - it's trying to print without quotes. Elements in my character vector really do contain quotes, which I'm trying to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringi` for this.  We can use the ICU metacharacter `\\P` to negate the matched values and `--` to subtract the negation of the comma.

```
library(stringi)
mcv <- c("version", "of", "mackinnon’s", "“dominance", "approach,”")
stri_replace_all_regex(mcv, "[\\P{Ll}--,]", "")
# [1] "version"    "of"         "mackinnons" "dominance"  "approach,"
```

I'm just learning ICU, but I think that's the right expression to use.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
strip(mcv, char.keep=',')
#[1] "version"    "of"         "mackinnons" "dominance"  "approach,"
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(mcv, '[^[:alnum:],]+', '')
#[1] "version"    "of"         "mackinnons" "dominance"  "approach,"
```

Or `base R`

```
 vapply(regmatches(mcv,gregexpr('[A-Za-z,]+', mcv)), paste,
                                    collapse="", character(1L))
#[1] "version"    "of"         "mackinnons" "dominance"  "approach,"
```

#### data

```
mcv <- c("version","of","mackinnon’s","“dominance","approach,”")
```

Answer (score 1):

these are "fancy" quotes -- I cut & pasted them from the screen (if you just use SHIFT-' [or whatever it is on your keyboard] you'll just get regular " quotes ...).

```
mcv <- c("version","of","mackinnon’s","“dominance","approach,”")
gsub("[’”“]","",mcv)
```

Another possibility (seems to work on my system but might? be system/locale/etc. specific?): convert weird characters to "#", or something else safe, and then get rid of them.

```
gsub("#","",iconv(mcv,"latin1","ASCII","#"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
gsub("[^[:print:]]", "", my.char.vector)
```

Comment: @BenBolker Use `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")` and try. Maybe it has to do something with the system locale.